# from google.cloud import bigquery ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, google-bigquery, dockerfile

After following the basic Google cloud run tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy),

I have been trying to deploy to something a bit more complex but without success..

My app.py starts with those imports:

```
import os
import uuid
import requests
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery
from flask import Flask
```

But when I try to run it I get the following logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker 
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 104, in init_process 
    super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi 
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load 
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp 
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app 
    __import__(module)
  File "/app/app.py", line 6, in <module> 
    from google.cloud import bigquery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Use the official Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn requests uuid google

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:app
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it looks like the correct python module to install for BigQuery is `google-cloud-bigquery`

`RUN pip install Flask gunicorn requests uuid google-cloud-bigquery`